# Regex Python - Replace any combination of line breaks, tabs, spaces, by single space

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a regular exp that enables me to replace all the line breaks and tabs (\n, \r, \t, etc.), and also any spaces before, after and inbetween by a single space. For example, the string

> 'Copyright ©\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t2019\n\t\t\tApple Inc. All rights
>   reserved.'

should turn into

> 'Copyright © 2019 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.'

Also, in the case that the original string was:

> 'Copyright © \n\t  \t\t\n    \t\t\t2019\n\t\t\t Apple Inc. All rights
>   reserved.'

The final result should be the same.

For a single line break, in the most simple case where there were no additional spaces, it would be something like

```
re.sub(r"\n", " ", html)
```

But as I don't deal often with regular expressions I don't know how to solve what I'm after.

Comment: You don't need a regular expression for this. `' '.join('Copyright ©\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t2019\n\t\t\tApple Inc. All rights reserved.'.split())` will give you the output you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using \s, which matches all whitespace characters.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Copyright ©\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t2019\n\t\t\tApple Inc. All rights reserved.'
>>> s = re.sub("\s+", " ", s)
>>> s
'Copyright © 2019 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.'
```

Comment: You can even do without the '+' after '\s'

Comment: `re.sub("\s", " ", s)` would certainly replace all tabs/newlines/etc with spaces. But it would replace consecutive whitespace characters with the same number of spaces. If you want "\t\t\t" to become a single space, for example, then `re.sub("\s+", " ", s)` is preferable.